# Easy way to check to see if value exists in a object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

How to check a value that exists in a nested object?

Lets say I have a data like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    title: 'New Posts',
    data: [
      {
        username: 'firstnamefromnewpost',
        content: 'this is some content that will go on forever and ever',
      },
      {
        username: 'name',
        content:
          'lost content goals lets',
      },
      {
        username: 'another name',
        content:
          'lost content goals lets start with some',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Different Posts',
    data: [
      {
        username: 'usernametag',
        content: 'this is some content that will go on forever and ever',
      },
      {
        username: 'name',
        content:
          'lost content goals lets start',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want to be able to find if `firstnamefromnewpost` exists within this array. Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: Exists how?  Only in the `username` property of the embedded `data` array of objects?  Or exists in any property on any object?

Comment: @jfriend00 Oo good question. I would like to get only in the username property of the embedded data, but would love your explanation on any property on any object too, that would be a good learning experience!

Comment: You've already accepted an answer and apparently don't need it from any property.   That would be more work to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Easy way?***

Probably you can use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) on the stringified array:

```js
const data = [
  {
    title: 'New Posts',
    data: [
      {
        username: 'firstnamefromnewpost',
        content: 'this is some content that will go on forever and ever',
      },
      {
        username: 'name',
        content:
          'lost content goals lets',
      },
      {
        username: 'another name',
        content:
          'lost content goals lets start with some',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Different Posts',
    data: [
      {
        username: 'usernametag',
        content: 'this is some content that will go on forever and ever',
      },
      {
        username: 'name',
        content:
          'lost content goals lets start',
      },
    ],
  },
];

var isExists = JSON.stringify(data).includes('firstnamefromnewpost');
console.log(isExists);
```

**OR:** If you want check the *username* property in the nested *data* array:

```js
const data = [
  {
    title: 'New Posts',
    data: [
      {
        username: 'firstnamefromnewpost',
        content: 'this is some content that will go on forever and ever',
      },
      {
        username: 'name',
        content:
          'lost content goals lets',
      },
      {
        username: 'another name',
        content:
          'lost content goals lets start with some',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Different Posts',
    data: [
      {
        username: 'usernametag',
        content: 'this is some content that will go on forever and ever',
      },
      {
        username: 'name',
        content:
          'lost content goals lets start',
      },
    ],
  },
];

function isExists(data, userName){
  for(const i of data){
    if(i.data.map(n => n.username).includes(userName)) return true
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(isExists(data, 'firstnamefromnewpost'));
```